# How to avoid exceptions (try catch block ) as a flow control

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

In the following method how can i aovid using try catch block but still call the correct method on id to get User/group? (Best Practices) Thanks in advance

```
     public Principal getPrincipal(String id) {
     Principal principal;
       try {
         principal = getUserById(id);
          return principal;

       } catch (Exception exception) {
        // nothing to do, maybe id is for group
    }

    principal = getGroup(id);
    return principal;
}
```

getUSerById(), throws a exception called EntityNotException,

Comment: As a best practice you should handle Checked Exceptions and your program should ideally not generate Unchecked Exceptions.

Comment: you can add `throws Exception` after method, like `public Principal getPrincipal(String id) throws Exception{` instead of `try..catch`.

Comment: As a general point, I'd be a bit more specific about the type of `Exception` that you catch. If you're only interested in the `EntityNotException`, only catch that exception.

Answer (score 0):

make function `getUserById`  such way that if there is no user found it return `null`

```
public Principal getPrincipal(String id) {

Principal principal = getUserById(id);

if (principal == null) {
          principal = getGroup(id);
    }
  return principal;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

In that case I'd consider having your `getUserById(String id)` return `null`, rather than an `EntityNotException` if no user can be found - Exceptions are to be used for *exceptional* circumstances, such as a failure beyond your control (Network connections vanished, no more memory is available, etc.). Your code could look something like the following:

```
public Principal getPrincipal(String id) {
    Principal principal = getUserById(id);

    if (principal == null) {
        //Try by group ID instead
        principal = getGroup(id);
    }
    return principal;
}
```

Make sure you're certain of the return types of your methods - from their names it doesn't sound like `getUserById(String id)` and `getGroup(String id)` definitely return a `Principal` object - the first sounds like it could return any type of `User` and the second  a `Group`, whatever that is.

Alternatively, given the caller of this method presumably knows whether they have a `userId` or a `groupId`, have you considered separate methods `getPrincipalByUserId(String userId)` and `getPrincipalByGroupId(String groupId)`?

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to avoid try/catch block if you cannot modify `getUserById(String)` method. That's fine to have such check, but be very careful when you just ignore an exception.

Also you can just extract a small *get method* like this:

```
public Principal getUserByIdIngorinException(String id) {
    try {
        return getUserById(id);
    } catch (Exception ignored) {
        // ignore the exception
    }
    return null;
}
```